# MERN stack in AWS 1

Tags: mern

node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn cmd',
path: 'cmd',
spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}

It will get error but I cannot expect the error